# Expanding variables before bash call/exec

Tags: bash

I know the basics of Bash but often miss the nuance and I'm having a problem using it to achieve what I had hoped would be a rather simple problem:

If I have the following in a bash script, which works exactly as I'd want it to:

```
cbType=`echo $configuration | jsawk -a 'return _.where(this,{name: "reference_data"})'`
```

It takes `$configuration` -- which is a JSON string -- and identifies the array element where *name* is "reference_data" and returns that object/hash definition only. Please note that this does use the very handy [**jsawk**](https://github.com/micha/jsawk) utility but it has been designed to be exhibit good command-line behaviour.

The problem is that when I remove the hard-coded "reference-data" with a variable it seems to not be able to reference the scope of the variable. So for instance, ...

```
myVar="\"reference_data\""
cbType=`echo $configuration | jsawk -a 'return _.where(this,{name: $myVar})'`
```

Does **not** work and instead returns a jsawk error of:

> jsawk: js error: ReferenceError: $myVar is not defined

Is there anything I can do to enforce that first the variable is expanded, *and then* the command string is executed?

Comment: Do you mind giving an example of where the quotes would go? I've tried quite a few combinations but none have worked yet.

Comment: variables won't be expanded if it's within single quotes.

Comment: Of course that makes sense ... not sure why all my historic days in Perl or PHP didn't make me think of that. On a side note, can you put that down as an answer and I'll mark that as correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declared variables won't be expanded if it's not within double quotes. So put your code inside double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
myVar="\"reference_data\""
cbType=$(echo "$configuration" | jsawk -a "return _.where(this,{name: $myVar})")
```

Comment: I'd probably have recommended the escaped quotes in the jsawk script instead of in the variable. In the variable could be seen to encourage that as a general pattern (which leads to things like [BashFAQ050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).